# Recursion, calling a function using input

Tags: python, function, recursion, input

I'm working on some recursion stuff. I've created some functions in the vein of the twelve days of xmas, but I can't think of a way to call a function using input. I'll give an example:

```
def day1():
    print 'A Partridge in a Pear Tree'
def day2():
    print '2 Turtle Doves'
    day1()
def day3():
    print '3 French Hens'
    day2()
```

I tried going the route of using if statements inside a function such as

```
def DaysOfXmas(n):
    if n == 1:
        day1()
    if n == 2:
        day2()
    if n == 3:
        day3()
```

But this feels like a horrible and messy way of doing it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any recursion in your examples

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* do `globals()['day%d' % n]()`, but that's even more horrible and messy.

Just put the functions into a collection. A list, for instance, or a dict if you need sparse or non-integer keys. `day_funcs = [day0, day1, day, day3]` (`day0` should propably be a placeholder, a non-callable works if you check the input before blindly getting the item and calling it - if not, the user gets an ugly error that seems totally unrelated) and use `day_funcs[n]()` in the dispatcher. You can make this more DRY in several ways: The one that requires the last typing (but would also fall down for other naming schemes) would be putting the functions (and *only* those) into a seperate module and, after importing them, defining `day_funcs = sorted(inspect.getmembers(the_module, isfunction))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
days = ['A Partridge in a Pear Tree',
        '2 Turtle Doves',
        '3 French Hens']

def sing(n=0):
    print days[n]
    try:
        sing(n+1)
    except IndexError:
        return
```

That's a simple example of looping with recursion. Don't do it in Python except to understand it, though. That function is much easier to write (and more efficient) with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind recursion is that you have one consistent set of operations that you perform on any arbitrary input, and you set one or more base cases that will perhaps do something special, and end the recursive call.

If you want to do something different for 12 input values, either consider using a map of output for the given input (then calling the function again with a decremented input value), or you have 12 base cases.